# how can I update, reloads and ajax the table without refreshing reactjs

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs, crud

I am having difficult time updating the table it only updates when refreshed I dont know where I went wrong it just happened that way I tried to debug it but it reads the data yet it only updates when refreshed

```
 handleUpdate(id, name, address,department,idx){ 

debugger
    const data = {
      'Employee_ID': id,
      'Employee_Name': name,
      'Address': address,
      'Department': department
    }
return fetch('http://localhost:5118/api/employeedetails/PutEmployeeDetail/'+id, {
       method: 'POST',
       headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
       body: JSON.stringify(data) })
      .then(function(response) {
      console.log(response)
        return response.json();
         this.forceUpdate();
          var jsonReturnedValue = [...this.state.jsonReturnedValue];
        jsonReturnedValue.setState({data:response});
        this.setState({jsonReturnedValue})

      })
      .then((result)=> {    
       })
      .catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
      }) 

}
```

Comment: why  `jsonReturnedValue.setState({data:response});` ? It may be breaking the execution ?

Comment: i just tried it @DJYadav but doesn't work

Comment: Well the issue is in the then function, before answering, please describe the type of **this.state.jsonReturnedValue** and **key+type of table data from response**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How to ajax based on my understanding
First install

```
npm i jquery -s
```

then import the jQuery

```
Import $ from 'jQuery';
```

then do ajax in your componentDidMount and do a function simillar to your componentDidMount

```
componentDidMount() {
  $.ajax({
  url:'http://localhost:5118/api/employeedetails/getemployeedetails/',
  success:(data)=>{
    this.setState({
      jsonReturnedValue:data
    })
  }
})
}
```

something similar like this

```
restartFunc(){
   $.ajax({
  url:'http://localhost:5118/api/employeedetails/getemployeedetails/',
  success:(data)=>{
    this.setState({
      jsonReturnedValue:data
    })
  }
})
}
```

then call it to your onclick inside your update

```
handleUpdate(id, name, address,department,idx){ 
    const data = {
      'Employee_ID': id,
      'Employee_Name': name,
      'Address': address,
      'Department': department
    }
return fetch('http://localhost:5118/api/employeedetails/PutEmployeeDetail/'+id, {
       method: 'POST',
       headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
       body: JSON.stringify(data) })
      .then(function(response) {
      })
       .then((result)=> {   
           this.restartFunc()
       })
      .catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
      }) 
this.setState({})
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This might fix the problem. You are using the return statement after the console.log statement which prevents execution of the code and don't use **jsonReturnedValue.setState({data:response});**

```
handleUpdate(id, name, address,department,idx){ 

debugger
    const data = {
      'Employee_ID': id,
      'Employee_Name': name,
      'Address': address,
      'Department': department
    }
       return 
       fetch('http://localhost:5118/api/employeedetails/PutEmployeeDetail/'+id, 
       {
       method: 'POST',
       headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
       body: JSON.stringify(data) })
      .then(function(response) {
      console.log(response)
        this.forceUpdate();
        var jsonReturnedValue = [...this.state.jsonReturnedValue];
        this.setState({jsonReturnedValue});
        return response.json();

      })
      .then((result)=> {    
       })
      .catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
      }) 

}
```